# Weird date/time discrepancy?

Tags: javascript, date

I've got an input on a webpage where the user is supposed to enter a date / time in a standard format, i.e.

`16/09/2014 18:00`

That value is then passed into the following snippet of code:

`var date = new Date(Date.parse(userDate))`

where `userDate` is the input. Then I send that date as part of an AJAX request:

```
var request = {
    ...
    "date" : date.toISOString()
    ...
    };
```

However, when I look at the request sent by my browser, `date` equals `2015-04-09T16:00:00.000Z`.

Can someone explain why this happens?

Comment: side note:Date.parse is redundant. javascript runtime does that for you behind screens.

Comment: `Date.parse("16/09/2014 18:00")` gives you an invalid date. So how are you *actually* parsing the date? Can you create a fiddle to demonstrate your problem?

Comment: It seems to be wrapping around into the 16th month of 2014, i.e. April 2015.

Comment: @MattBurland Only in Chrome -- Firefox does parse it. (Although it does so.. sort-of correctly? There indeed may be something missing here.) ECMAScript [specifies one required date format](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15) and [freely allows implementations to supply any other implementation-specific formats](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.4.2). Some browsers support the OP's date as a implementation-specific format; some don't.

Comment: The *real* solution to this problem is to not allow the user to enter a date in a textbox and instead use a date picker control. Letting a user enter a date unrestricted will cause no end of headaches.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you use RFC2822 or ISO 8601 format with `Date.parse()` according to the [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse).